# Intuition of the Lorentz norm in an Wikipedia article

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, intuition, harmonic-analysis, weak-lp-spaces

It is said in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_space) that the Lorentz space norm ${\|f\|_{L^{1,\infty }}}$  with ${f(x)=|x-1|^{-1}}$ is the area of the **largest** rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes that can be inscribed in the graph.

However, direct calculation shows that the area of **any** inscribed rectangle is
$$
\frac{(2-x)-x}{|1-x|}=2,\quad x\in(-\infty, 1).
$$

The "*largest* rectangle" observation seems rather trivial. Is there something wrong with the Wikipedia interpretation?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The equality $\|f\|_{L^{1,\infty }}=\sup_{t>0} (t\{x:|f(x)|>t\})= t\{x:|f(x)|>t\}$ 
for any $t>0$ holds only for this special function $f$, not for an arbitrary function of $L^{1,\infty}$. So, I guess, the function $f$ can be a considered as an $L^{1,\infty}$ counterpart of a constant function $g(t)=c>0$ in $L^\infty$ for which $\|g\|_{ L^\infty}=\sup_t | g(t)|=g(t)$ for any $t$.